# Merge 2 csv files with the same names and number of columns

Tags: r, csv

I have 2 csv files with the same length of columns with the same names.

I want to merge them to one df.

Here what I try to do

```
df1 = read.csv("/data/1.csv", header=TRUE)
df2 = read.csv("/dataf/2.csv", header=TRUE)

df = merge(df1, df2)
```

When I time the `ncol(df)` the number is right 25. However when I type `nrow(df)` it is 0. Why?

Also I tried `cbind(df1,d2)` and it gives me this error

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 9247, 6847
```

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it will be very difficult to guess what went wrong for you. The only answer to give at this point would be the obvious....your merge did not work correctly. We'd really need at least the first few values (head) of df1 and df2.

Comment: Do you want to bind rows or columns? You could try dplyr::bind_rows or dplyr::bind_cols.

Answer (score 0):

This will merge all the CSV files in the directory.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("/dir")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: That's actually an answer in python while this question is for a problem in R.